# String: replacing spaces by a number

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split, gsub

I would like to replace every `blank spaces` in a string by a fixnum (which is the number of `blank spaces`).

Let me give an example:

```
s = "hello,   how          are  you ?"
omg(s) # => "hello,3how10are2you1?"
```

Do you see a way (sexy if possible) to update a string like this?

Thank you Rubists :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gsub` can be fed a block for the "replace with" param, the result of the block is inserted into place where the match was found. The argument to the block is the matched string. So to implement this we capture as much whitespace as we can ( `/\s+/` ) and feed that into the block each time a section is found, returning that string's length, which gets put back where the whitespace was originally found.

Code:

```
s = "hello,   how          are  you ?"
res = s.gsub(/\s+/) { |m| m.length }
puts res
# => hello,3how10are2you1?
```

Comment: I would have +1 this answer if it included an explanation.

Comment: Wow, ruby is so expressive! It's a bit longer in python:
`omg = lambda s: re.sub(r'\s+', lambda m: str(len(m.group())), s)`

Comment: In Ruby 1.9, it can be further shortened to `s.gsub(/\s+/, &:length)`.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible to do this via an array split : Javascript example

```
var s = "hello,   how          are  you ?";

function omg( str ) {
    var strArr = str.split('');
    var count = 0;
    var finalStr = '';
    for( var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++ ) {
        if( strArr[i] == ' ' ) {
            count++;
        }
        else 
        {
            if( count > 0 ) {
                finalStr += '' + count;
                count = 0;
            }  

            finalStr += strArr[i];
        }
    }
    return finalStr
}

alert( omg( s ) ); //"hello,3how10are2you1?"
```

Lol, this seems the best it can be for javascript

Comment: Thank you @pico.creator. I would like to do it in Ruby, but your piece of code is also useful, so I'm adding +1 anyway :)

Comment: Hmm i thought it would be easily convertible, not exactly a good ruby user. So this example can be easily understood